# Maven POM packaging with dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm trying to construct a codebase where subsystems can be developed as maven modules, without the importing POM needing to concern itself with the internal structure of the maven module.

The "importing" pom

```
<project>
  <artifactId>application</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>submodule-1</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The "imported" pom

```
<project>
  <artifactId>submodule-1</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>api</module>
    <module>implementation</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>implementation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This does seem to work, at least partially; the generated JARs appear to be on the classpath during `mvn package`. IntelliJ shows the application has a dependency on `submodule-1` and transitively on `api` and `implementation`. However, `mvn dependency:tree` fails while building `submodule-1` saying

> Could not resolve dependencies for project submodule-1:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact api:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

I'm trying to determine if this is a valid pattern, that of having packaging of `pom`, with defined dependencies which are also defined modules in the POM.

Have I stumbled upon a *working-but-not-supported* edge case, or is the dependency plugin broken in some way, or I'm breaking it in some way, or something else?

Comment: An artifact with packaging `pom` will never produce an `jar` cause it will never code and usually shouldn't have dependencies (some exceptions exist)...cause a usual dependency will create a `jar` file can be used as dependency. So if you replace your dependency artifact from `submodule-1` with `api` it could work...furthermore your `submodule-1` contains modules `api` and `implementation`why are having the same artifacts/modules defined as dependencies? This does not make sense?

Comment: I think you should carefully read the [maven documentation on project aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Aggregation)

Comment: The `api` and `implementation` modules in `submodule-1` are just examples. The importing project shouldn't need to care how the submodule is actually implemented. `submodule-1` may as well have been composed of `worker-1`, `worker-2` and `common`. I'm also not expecting `submodule-1` to produce a jar, but rather to make it possible to depend on the submodule as a whole, rather than having to know about its internals and import them individually.